# Own SSH key file to tie up for SSH access to a foreign Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

We are to have SSH access to client's Linux server for code installation and launch. As the client has given us FTP connection
client has also said:
"SSH access: Can you **send me your SSH key**. I will **connect it to our Linux server**."

**Is this procedure correct, valid ?**

Seems to me client should generate SSH key and forward to us for SSH access...

Answer (score 2):

I think that's correct, you can create your own ssh keys with `ssh-gen`:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

You must send him the public key, for him to add to `authorized_keys` and enable you to access.

You may need to additionally add the private key to the `ssh-agent` for it to use by default:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add /dir_to_private_key
```

Comment: if you already have private/public key, you can give public key, they usualy look lie `ssh-rsa AAA-a-long-line== a comment`

Comment: You can indeed reuse your existing public key. However, if you're providing the key to a third party you may _prefer_ to generate a separate key that can be discarded when you've finished with it